# Format function vs Parameters in sql injection scenarios?

Tags: sql, delphi, sql-injection

I know about the uses of parameters in sql sentences, But just for curiosity is safe to use  the Format function to prevent sql injections instead of use paramters.

like this sample

```
sCustomer : string
begin
 AdoSql.CommandText:=Format('Select SUM(value) result from invoices where customer=%s',[QuotedStr(sCustomer)]);
end;
```

Comment: I think title should have been `QuotedStr function vs Parameters in sql injection scenarios?` but changing it, will break some answers here. the *issue* here is about `QuotedStr` and not `Format`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That would *probably* be secure against SQL injection, assuming `QuotedStr` works as expected and there are no edge cases that can break it.  (Which is by no means guaranteed.  As Linas pointed out in a comment, MySql lets you use `\'` to escape out quotes.  Other DBMSs probably have similar capabilities.  An attacker with enough theoretical knowledge of the system would be able to exploit them.)

However, even if QuotedStr was good enough, it's still better to use parameters for a different reason: performance.  When you separate your parameters from your query, you can end up sending the exact same query code multiple times with different parameters.  If you do that, the database can cache a lot of the work it does in computing the query, so your DB access gets faster.  That doesn't work (or at least not as well) when you mix the parameters into the query code itself.

Comment: +1 for the comment about "cache", many SQL Servers can reuse the  execution plan of the sql senteces.

Comment: That would probably be insecure in MySQL because MySQL permits \' to escape a quote so QuotedStr won't help here.

Comment: Note that MS SQL Server can "Auto-parameterise" queries. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee343986%28v=sql.100%29.aspx for examples.

Answer (score 6):

Any time you build up an SQL string by concatenating strings together, there is potential for an injection attack, no matter how safe you think access to those strings are.  For all you know, someone could run your app inside a debugger, put a breakpoint on the result of `QuotedStr()`, and modify its contents before allowing `Format()` to see it.

Using actual SQL parameters is the safest way to go.  Not only does it avoid injections, but it also allows the SQL engine to decide how best to format the parameters to its own needs so you don't have to worry about formatting the values in your own code, it works well with strongly-typed languages (like Delphi).  Not to mention the performance benefits of being able to prepare the SQL statement on the server side ahead of time before then executing it in your code, even multiple times, drastically reducing the traffic between the client and server and increasing overall performance.

```
var
  sCustomer : string 
begin 
  AdoSql.CommandText := 'Select SUM(value) result from invoices where customer=:Customer'; 
  AdoSql.Prepared := True;
  ... 
  AdoSql.Parameters['Customer'].Value := sCustomer; 
  AdoSql1.ExecSQL;
  ...
  AdoSql.Parameters['Customer'].Value := sCustomer;
  AdoSql1.ExecSQL;
  ...
  AdoSql.Prepared := False;
end;
```

Comment: That first paragraph's a little bit silly.  SQL injection is basically about gaining unauthorized access to the database.  But if someone has debug-level access to your app itself, they don't *need* a SQL injection attack to gain access to the database; they can be assumed to already have access to it, at the same privilege level as the app itself.

Comment: Not if the app uses an encrypted connection to the database, or if the attacker cannot, or doesn't want to, determine what kind of database is being used or how to access it directly.  Let the app do all the work, just change the SQL that is executed.

Comment: In this scenario, then using parameters would also be insecure as the user could change the parameters' values - something which I sometimes do when debugging my own apps.

Comment: Even if the attacker changes the parameter values, using parameters is still safer.  As I said, parameters allow the DB engine to ensure the values are safe and formatted properly.  In other words, passing an unquoted string to a parameter (which is what you are supposed to do) allows the engine to still handle the string correctly when it executes the query.  This is why parameters are used to avoid injection attacks in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

No, `Format` offers no safety from SQL injection. It's no different from ordinary string concatenation in that regard.

The part of the code in the question that does anything against SQL injection is the call to `QuotedStr`, which you could use with or without `Format`. It's not as reliable as real parameterized queries, though.

The only advantage of `Format` in this context is that the entire string template is in one place, so you're less likely to get spacing and punctuation wrong than you would be if you had to construct the string with successive `+` operations, where the SQL apostrophes could get lost among the Delphi apostrophes.