# Error: "No value given for one or more required parameters" when updating Database

Tags: sql, database, delphi, ado

I am currently working with a small program where a field must be selected of a DBGrid and then with the help of an inputbox, the value can be updated.

The Database has a field called `CaseNumber` that has the primary key. The code must identify the field name of the field and the case number of the selected row, with that information, the database can be updated.

Here is a copy of my code:

```
procedure TfrmManagePatientInformation.btnChangeClick(Sender: TObject);
var NewValue, Fieldname : String;
    CaseNumber : Integer;
begin
// Make sure that the Case Number will not be changed
if DBGridPatients.SelectedField.FieldName = 'CaseNumber' then
begin
 MessageDlg('The Case Number of a patient cannot be changed!',mtError,[mbOK],0);
 Exit;
end
else
begin
 // Get Fieldname
 Fieldname := DBGridPatients.SelectedField.FieldName;

 // Get Case Number of the selected row
 CaseNumber := StrToInt(DBGridPatients.Fields[0].Value);

 // Get new value
 NewValue := InputBox('New Value','Please enter the new value!','');

 // Change the value permanently
 PatientQuery.Active := False;
 PatientQuery.SQL.Text := 'Update CurrentPatients SET ' + QuotedStr(FieldName) + ' = ' + QuotedStr(NewValue) + ' where CaseNumber = :CaseNumber';
 PatientQuery.Parameters.ParamByName('CaseNumber').Value := CaseNumber;
 PatientQuery.ExecSQL;

 MessageDlg('Information changed successfully!',mtConfirmation,[mbOK],0);
```

Each time I run it, it gives me an error:

> No value given for one or more required parameters.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: What is `PatientQuery.SQL.Text` just prior to execution?  Why not make `NewValue` a named parameter as well?

Comment: What component is PatientQuery ? is it an AdoQuery ? if so check the executeoptions it should be empty

Comment: @GuidoG Yes it is an AdoQuery, but it is empty

Comment: FieldName should not have QuotedStr.

Comment: @Zenyl then check if PatientQuery.ExecuteOption = []

Comment: Why are you using this completely unnecessary method of updating the fields of your table???  If you use Delphi's db-aware components, including the DBGrid, you can edit your data in the gui and then have your app automatically generate the Sql statements necessary to do the update and send the update to the server.  Shall I post a simple example as an answer?

Comment: Have you ever heard of sql injection?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, QuotedStr protects against sql injection in this case. but using parameters is almost always a good idea.

Comment: @kobik not completely

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I agree. when there is a doubt, there is no doubt. I do not know which DBMS OP is using, and I can't predict future sql syntax changes and features..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128171/format-function-vs-parameters-in-sql-injection-scenarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Kobik's answer is the correct one for the point you specifically asked about.

This is another way to address the point, namely how to update data without having to create Sql UPDATE statements yourself.  Try this

1. If you don't already have one, add to your form a DBNavigator connected to the same DataSource as your DBGrid.  Keep an eye at runtime on the changing state of its buttons.
2. In your code block which opens the AdoQuery, add the following lines after PatientQuery.Open

:

```
  DBGrid1.Options := DBGrid1.Options + [dgEditing];
  DBGrid1.Columns[0].ReadOnly := True;
```

The above assumes your PK is displayed in the LH column of the grid, hence the index 0.

The option `dgEditing` allows you to click in any cell (except the PK ones, because we've set those to ReadOnly) and change the value.  Notice that when you do this at runtime, the tick and cross buttons on the DBNavigator become enabled so that you can save or abandon the change(s).  Notice also that if you click in another row while you're editing a cell, the change you've made is automatically posted to the dataset.

And, at its simplest, that's all there is to it.  On the same Component Palette tab as the DBGrid, you'll also find various other db-aware component that you can use in a similar way, in particular the TDBEdit and TDBMemo.

If you need any help about this way of working (which is the standard Delphi way of editing DB data), try googling a bit and, if you're still stuck, ask a new q here on SO.

Comment: How is this answer can be accepted to the question asked? it should have been a comment.

Comment: @kobik:  I thought it was SO's policy that it is up the the OP which answer is accepted.  The reason I posted it is that I've seen several qs recently where the OP has been unnecessarily constructing UPDATE statements when they could have perfectly well have used TDataSet's inherent updating capability, and in one of them the OP had run into virtually the same problem as this one.  I disagree that it should have been a comment - it seems legitimate to me that an answer can show a method which avoids the problem arising in the first place.  Ymmv ...

Comment: No, it's still a (good/elaborate/productive) *comment*. but it's not an *answer* to the question asked. You are suggesting OP to solve the specific Q error `"No value given for one or more required parameters"` by not using an UPDATE statement and re-designing the app. which is fine. but the question *is* about UPDATE and bogus usage of parameters and the sql statement. I have no complaints to *You*. But, I have no motivation to leave my answer on, wich was in fact initially accepted. feel free to edit yours and address the Q asked, so it will be helpful for future SO users. Cheers.